# Set current schema for oracle connection using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm migrating a lot of code from `cx_Oracle` to `sqlalchemy`. The point I'm struggling with, is the proper way to set the current schema that should be used for the querys.

The ways I've found, try to pass the schema information to a conncection string in `create_engine` if the db driver support this. `cx_Oracle`doesn't.

Or the schema is hard coded in a declarative base model via `__table_args__`, which is not useful in my case, because the schema is different on the test and productive server.

Using `schema_translate_map` as described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#translation-of-schema-names) was promising, but it turns out, that I have to call `execution_options()` before each query, which is not feasible.

I ended up running a `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = myschema` after creating the session. But this doesn't feel right. In particular because one has to sanitize the schema name, as this is read from a config file and must be treated like user input.

This is how it looks like now:

**model.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String)
    lastname = Column(String)

    @hybrid_property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}"
```

**app.py:**

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.orm

import model


class Application:
    def __init__(self, user, passwd, host, sid, schema):
        self._engine, self.session = Application.init_database(user, passwd, host, sid, schema)

    @staticmethod
    def init_database(user, passwd, host, sid, schema):
        db_url = f"oracle://{user}:{passwd}@{host}/{sid}"

        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_url, echo=True)
        session = sqlalchemy.orm.Session(bind=engine)

        session.execute(f"ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = {schema!s}")

        return engine, session

    def get_user(self, id):
        return self.session.query(model.User).filter_by(id=id).one_or_none()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application("username", "userpwd", "myhost", "mysid", "myschema")
    user = app.get_user(1)

    print(user.full_name)
```

Comment: Hm, using [@event.listens_for](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments) for connecting via `cx_oracle` and setting the [current_schema](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.current_schema) seems to be a way. Don't know if it's best practice?